# What would be the correct Spanish translation?

Tags: translation

I'm helping in the translation of an article on code theory and I got the following: $t$-frameproof and $t$-wise intersecting, but I don't know what its correct translation into Spanish would be. Can you help me please?

the definition goes like this:

> we say that a code $\mathcal{C}$ is $t$-frameproof, or $t$-wise intersecting, if the supports of any $t$
> nonzero codewords have a nonempty common intersection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These articles on encoding [[1](https://upcommons.upc.edu/bitstream/handle/2117/193058/Fernandez-Soriano-Domingo-Seb%C3%A9.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y) and [2](https://web.ua.es/en/recsi2014/documentos/papers/codigos-con-propiedades-de-localizacion-basados-en-matrices-de-bajo-sesgo.pdf)] in Spanish gives some suggestions for the translation of technical words in that field. Many words are kept in the original English.

The word "frameproof" is translated as "código a prueba de incriminaciones", abbreviated CI, so that $t$-frameproof could be rendered as $t$-CI (or you might just write $t$-frameproof and note the Spanish translation of "frameproof").

A $t$-wise intersection is "una intersección $t$-tuplas".